# React Native timemixin cancel timer timeout

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, settimeout, mixins

I found out how to cancel Javascript's timeout but how can I cancel a timer mixin? Timermixin is recommended for use with React Native over the Javascript timeout.

```
var TimerMixin = require('react-timer-mixin');

this.setTimeout(() => {this.setState({results: ' '})}, 1800)
```

I need to have it canceled if other actions are executed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Solution**

```
var clearId = this.setTimeout(() => {this.setState({results: ' '})}, 1800);
this.setState({ clearId: clearId});
```

*...somewhere later when you want to cancel the setTimeout call*

```
this.clearTimeout(this.state.clearId)
```

**Explanation**

You can cancel it the same way you would a regular setTimeout, by using **clearTimeout**. clearTimeout will prevent the function from running if it hasn't been called yet.

When setTimeout is called, it "*returns a number representing the ID value of the timer that is set. Use this value with the clearTimeout() method to cancel the timer.*" http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Since I imagine you'll want to call clearTimeout in a separate function, you can store the clearId as a state property so it can be easily referenced later in a separate function.

If want to learn more about Timers in React Native, I found this documentation helpful https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/timers.html.

**Also**

By using the TimerMixin (instead of the regular setTimeout method), the setTimeout call will be prevented automatically if the component **unmounts**. Very useful! This is why you should make sure to use the TimerMixin instead of regular Timer methods.

"We found out that the primary cause of fatals in apps created with React Native was due to timers firing after a component was unmounted."
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/timers.html

The TimerMixin will avoid this and make sure all Timer calls are cleared when a component unmounts.